# How to build LuaPlus on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lua, jam

I downloaded JamPlus (after expending quite some time discovering that this was the specific Jam derivate needed and didn't ship with the download), and set my PATH variable as dictated, and the thing doesn't work.

Specifically, Jam lists a trunk of errors, like not being able to find source folders and writing to nonexistent projects, and when attempting to build what actually did output with Visual Studio, it skips building 69 projects and fails to build one other.

How can I build LuaPlus? Or even just ... include the source directly or something ...?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just include the source directly. If you want to build a library, don't include the files:
1. `lua.c` (Lua stand-alone interpreter)
2. `luac.c` (Lua compiler)
3. `luace.h luace.c` (A port of Lua for Windows CE)
4. `LuaPlusAll.cpp`